# Mass Insert/Update PDO MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm programming a new function for a Symfony2 project that handles with many entries (about 30k), there are many DBs hosted in different servers and for this reason is performance very important, to add some speed to our application we have a core db with not so much data this db has a cache table in one DB, and there is another db to store all transactions.

The cache table looks like:

```
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| object_id      | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| object_type    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sum24h         | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sum3d          | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sum7d          | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sum30d         | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sum_alltime    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

It contains just sums of the data so I wanted to build a MySQL PDO Query to update the data, or insert it if the entry is new

```
INSERT INTO `table`
(object_id,object_type, sum24h,sum3d,sum7d,sum30d,sum_alltime)
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),
       (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE object_id = ?, object_type = ?, sum24h = ?, sum3d = ?, sum7d = ?, sum30d = ?, sum_alltime = ?
```

So that would work for one value but, in my case I want to set the corresponding values, for example for the existing values:

```
$data1 = array('object_id' => 1, 'object_type'=> 1,
        'sum24h' => 11101, 'sum3d' => 301, 'sum7d' => 701, 'sum30d' => 3001, 'sum_alltime' => 10001);

$data2 = array('object_id' => 2, 'object_type'=> 1,
        'sum24h' => 401, 'sum3d' => 101, 'sum7d' => 801, 'sum30d' => 1001, 'sum_alltime' => 2001);
```

So asumming that both objects exists in the db it is possible to update both using a singular query?

PD: I would use Doctrine to do it but sadly there are too much operations involved and it takes too long, and I would run an Cronjob Script in the remote server but that is not wished :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite easy

```
INSERT INTO `table` (object_id,object_type,sum24h,sum3d,sum7d,sum30d,sum_alltime)
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE object_id = VALUES(object_id),object_type = VALUES(object_type),sum24h = VALUES(sum24h),sum3d = VALUES(sum3d),sum7d = VALUES(sum7d),sum30d = VALUES(sum30d),sum_alltime = VALUES(sum_alltime)
```